# Как загрузить данные из CSV файла с выбором строк по условию INTO TABLE WHEN?

Tags: sql, oracle, csv

Есть CSV файл. Пример данных:

```
Data1|data2|data3
Data4|data5|data6
Ctr|1|2
Lst|1|30
Lst|1|40
Lst|1|50
Data7|data8|data9
Ctr|2|3
Lst|2|60
Lst|2|70
```

Таблица, куда эти данные должны быть загружены:

```
 create table me.control (dtype varchar2 (8), Idctl varchar2 (8), ltype varchar2 (8), Idsub varchar2 (8));
```

Используя SQL*Loader хочу получить такой результат:

```
dtype | Idctl|ltype  | Idsub
------+------+-------+------
Ctr   | 1    |  NULL | 2
Lst   | 1    |  30   | NULL
Lst   | 1    |  40   | NULL
Lst   | 1    |  50   | NULL
Ctr   | 2    | NULL  | 3
Lst   | 2    |  60   | NULL
Lst   | 2    |  70   | NULL
```

Пробовл со следуюшими параметрами в контрольном файле:

```
LOAD DATA
CHARACTERSET UTF8
TRUNCATE
INTO TABLE control WHEN (1:3) = 'Ctr' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "|"
TRAILING NULLCOLS (   
    dtype  CHAR, 
    Idctl  CHAR,  
    Idsub  CHAR)

INTO TABLE control WHEN (1:3) = 'Lst'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "|"
TRAILING NULLCOLS (   
     dtype CHAR,
     Idctl CHAR,
     ltype CHAR)
```

Но вторая часть не загрузилась - 0 записей.

```
DTYPE    IDCTL    LTYPE    IDSUB   
-------- -------- -------- --------
Ctr      1        null     2       
Ctr      2        null     3
```

Как это можно исправить?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Load data from multiple lines with condition controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63825544) от участника [@fati lem](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1562847/fati-lem)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/63825544

Answer (score 3):

Как сказано [в документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-control-file-contents.html#GUID-7C0925AD-7156-4C30-BF19-3C3D3628A7DE):

> **Note:**
> A key point when using multiple `INTO TABLE` clauses is that *field scanning continues from where it left off* when a new `INTO TABLE` clause is processed. The remainder of this section details important ways to make use of that behavior. It also describes alternative ways of using fixed field locations or the `POSITION` parameter.

При обработке условия `Lst`, SQL*Loader продолжает искать столбцы в текущей строке.

Можно сбросить это условие, определив первое поле с параметром `position` для сброса в начало строки:

```
into table control when dtype = 'Ctr' 
fields terminated by "|"
trailing nullcols (   
    dtype  CHAR, 
    Idctl  CHAR,  
    Idsub  CHAR)

into table control when dtype = 'Lst'
fields terminated by "|"
trailing nullcols (   
    dtype position(1:3) CHAR,
    Idctl CHAR,
    ltype CHAR)        
BEGINDATA
Data1|data2|data3
Data4|data5|data6
Ctr|1|2
Lst|1|30
Lst|1|40
Lst|1|50
Data7|data8|data9
Ctr|2|3
Lst|2|60
Lst|2|70
```

Результат:

```
$ sqlldr me/me@dbsrv/pdb1 control=test.ctl

Table CONTROL:
  2 Rows successfully loaded.

Table CONTROL:
  5 Rows successfully loaded.
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63829499) от участника [@Chris Saxon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485955/chris-saxon)</sub>